# An error occurred: Command failed: ./gradlew lib:uploadArchives

Tags: walmart-electrode

When i execute the command ern run-android getting following error
An error occurred: Command failed: ./gradlew lib:uploadArchives

Also it doesn't generate android folder as it got created while creating application through react native

Gradle updated and exported as well

Error should be get resolved

Answer (score 0):

Electrode : When  execute the command ern run-android getting following error An error occurred: Command failed: ./gradlew lib:uploadArchives error is got resolved.

Following are the steps to resolve the error:
1. open the terminal and type sudo su to become the root user
2. Install the gradle
3. Edit the ~/.bashrc and add the followings

export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/$USER/Android/Sdk   # comment you can also change the $USER with your username or can set the path where you have installed Android

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/build-tools
```

also optional in case still getting error add following line as well (Set gradle pat according to instllation in your system)
`GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle`
 export PATH=$PATH:$GRADLE_HOME/gradle5.5

4. Save the file
5. Reboot the system
6. Login with root user into the terminal and execute following command once
   after connecting the mobile device

   $ adb devices
7. now run the ern run-android command